# What external touchpads work on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad

By "work", I mean recognizing clicks, taps, multi-finger clicks, multi-finger taps, simultaneous horizontal and vertical scroll using 2 fingers, pinch to unzoom and vice versa.

By multi-finger, I think 3 fingers recognition is enough. 4 is a bonus :) Example: 3 fingers tap to work as the middle click to fast close browser tabs or opening links in a new tab.

By external, I mean not built-in laptop touchpads.

So, know such a touchpad working on Ubuntu?

* I tried posting the [same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/867347/13330) on askubuntu.com but was put on hold and someone recommended posting the question on Hardware Recommendations.

What I found so far:

1. [Logitch Touchpad T650](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/touchpad-t650) supports [some gesture but not all](https://askubuntu.com/a/324338/13330). [Requires a firmware update that can be done only on Windows](https://askubuntu.com/a/423037/13330) :(
2. Apple Magic Trackpd 1 - Found a [5 years old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/45269/13330) and one [open question of late](https://askubuntu.com/q/807940/13330).
3. Apple Magic Trackpd 2 - couldn't find info on Ubuntu/Linux support.

Comment: What is your budget?